# document.body is undefined even though script is loaded in <body> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, onload, script-tag

We have essentially this in a large scale React SPA:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/application.js"></script>
    <script src="a-third-party-remote-script.js"></script>
    <script>var configFor3rdPartyStuff = {keyvalstuff}</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside application we might do basically this (in some deeply nested import):

```
const Popup = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.textContent = 'hello world'
    document.body.appendChild(div)
  }, [])
}

ReactDOM.render(<Popup />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

The `document.body` is >99% of the time present, but in a few cases (< 50 cases over 2 months, with many thousands of page views per day), the `document.body` seems to be null, as rollbar is catching and logging an error right where we are doing `document.body.appendChild(div)`. Is this because we need to wait for the `window.onload` event? Or something else?

Two potential solutions come to mind. One is to dynamically load the `script` elements programmatically, after `window.onload`. The other is to wait for `window.onload` inside the app entry point, making the onload callback do `ReactDOM.render...`. As I can't reproduce this issue I am not sure it is the solution. What do you think should be done for the ideal architecture to prevent this error?

*So far, the error only seems to be occurring on Chrome for Windows, and Chrome Mobile WebView on Android, if that makes a difference.*

Is it possible that the customer closes the browser while the app is still loading, and then when they reopen the app, the code that loaded runs, but might be cut off, and it runs before the body is ready? I don't think so but trying to think outside the box.

Comment: Could it be an obscure browser accounting for these ~1% of incidents?

Comment: Possible, 4 errors in one couple-minute time stretch was with `Chrome Mobile WebView 90.0.4430`. It appears the others over the 2 months are on Windows 10 using chrome versions 90 or 91, like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36`.

Comment: Also, it hasn't occurred in the past 2 weeks.

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about these edge-cases. Without a clear way to reproduce or at least an official user bug report, it's a lot of effort for insignificant gain in my opinion.

Comment: `document.body` becomes not null the moment the `<body>` start tag is parsed, so there's no need to wait for onload. But in heavy JS environment, there's no guarantee that `document.body` will remain forever not null. I suggest checking that there is no scenario where DOM manipulations of your app result in the `<body>` element being either destroyed or moved such that it isn't a child of the root element or that the root element has ceased to be an `<html>` element, any of which would cause `document.body` to return null.

Comment: Even a user's browser extension/plugin could be messing with your app, which is something that you have no power over, and it's fine!